# Apache httpd server-info and server-status

Tags: apache, server, httpd.conf, status, info

I am on Windows 7, using Apache 2.2.29. 
I modified my httpd.conf file to load moduels for mod-info.so and mod-status.so
and in my extra/httpd-info.conf, I updated server-status and server-info Location stancas to allow from

So, in my httpd.conf, I uncommented these:

```
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
```

and in my extra/httpd-info.conf, I modified as below to add my ip-address in "Allow from":

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from my-ip-address:no-port#
</Location>

<Location /server-info>
    SetHandler server-info
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from my-ip-address-no-port
</Location>
```

If I just enter my-ip-address:my-port in browser, I get

```
"It Works!"
```

However, when I try to get info and status of my server, I get

for server-info:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /server-info was not found on this server.
```

for server-status:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /server-status on this server.
```

I am new to Apache, please provide explanation.
Much appreciated,

Comment: Go to the Apache error log.  If you're on a Linux server, it's probably under /var/log/httpd or /var/log/apache2, and probably called error_log or error.log . Grep through it for errors related to /server-info and /server-status .  What do you see?

Answer (score 1):

On modern windows, If you edit httpd.conf from your normal user account you can end up creating a 2nd copy specific to your userid that the server doesn't see. Make sure to edit it as Administrator.